# How To Get IIS App Pool Memory Usage

Tags: iis, memory, cpu, iis-express, worker-process

I'm searching for IIS app pool memory usage on the web but I can not get any result like I want. I am wondering how can I get specific app pool CPU size in C#?

PS: I tried to start/stop app pool and it works but I don't know how can I access cpu usage.

Comment: Application pool itself has no memory usage. Worker processes of a pool are the entities that consume memory. So in your case, use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` to get worker processes of an application pool, and then using the standard `Process` API you can access the process memory usage.

Comment: thank you @LexLi . im so hesistate about adding new library to project. but it works for me , so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Process status (memory usage/CPU usage) can be queried via `Process` class.

To glue with IIS, you need to use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API to get worker process information from an application pool.

This API is not an extra library, but shipped with Windows as part of IIS 7 and above (%windir%\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll).